# javafx scene.lookup

Tags: javafx, scenegraph

I am converting an existing swing app to JavaFX.  I would think that this code would return a node called "#paneRightBottom", but it returns null.  Using the netbeans debugger I am able to drill down on the "topNode" and find the "#paneRightBottom" node six levels deep, so it is there.  I have read the online docs and think that I should be getting a node.  Does anyone have an idea of where I've gone wrong?

```
        Node topNode = FXMLLoader.load(AFI.class.getResource("afimain.fxml"));
        System.out.println(topNode.getId());
        Node node = topNode.lookup("#paneRightBottom");
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if the node, which you are trying to lookup, has an `id="paneRightBottom"` and not `fx:id="paneRightBottom"`. If it has then give more details by posting your fxml file too.

Comment: Thanks @Uluk, I had already marked up the xml to account for the different id formats.  I'm still looking at it but I believe that it has to do with split panes not considering the panes to be children but rather items.  This makes writing a traversing method a bit less elegant, having to use instanceof to check for split panes seems wrong somehow.  I didn't consider split panes as a problem so didn't

Comment: @BobSmith. If you didn't look at yet, see [JavaFX 2.0 + FXML - strange lookup behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12324799/682495). I think the answer can be applied to your use case as well.