# How to access the vbox that I created via javafx scene builder?

Tags: java, javafx

I have added a vbox from scene builder and set its visibility to false.  Based on certain condition I want to set visibility to true.  How do I do it?

I am new to java as well, so I am not able to sort out the problem with root.getChildren() which throws a compilation error, getChildren() has protected access in Parent. Could you please help?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `if (condition) vbox.setVisible(true);`?

Comment: Hi,Thanks, I am not adding vbox from code (the class that extend Application).  I have added it from scene builder, so I need to get hold of this particular vbox instance/ID somehow and then set its visibility I guess. The code you gave will work if I have added vbox to the scene from code, but I dont want to do that, just because adding it from scene builder is more easier.

I also learnt that we could achieve this by using reflection and also learnt few points against it, so not sure as of now.

Comment: For better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Not sure if this is the right way;

    public  void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Window.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
  
//Now based on certain condition I would like to make vbox which I created in Window.fxml, visible to user
  
// how do I do it?

Comment: Sorry, I could not add the code in the right format

Comment: After lot of searching,  [I found the answer here,][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324799/javafx-2-0-fxml-strange-lookup-behaviour

Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

It takes three steps.

1. Define controller Java class in your FXML file. Either in SceneBuilder or directly in XML.
2. In controller define field VBox and annotate it with `@FXML` and its name use in XML like `fx:id`. This will tell to JavaFX to bind your field with correct instance of VBox.
3. Do whatever you want with VBox

XML definition (notice `fx:controller` and `fx:id`):

```
    <BorderPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1024.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="foo.bar.MainController">
      <center>
        <VBox fx:id="content" fillWidth="true" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      ...
```

Controller class:

```
    public class MainController {
          @FXML
          private VBox content;
    }
```

If you want to call controller class from outside, you will get instance of controller from right instance of `FXMLLoader` like this:

```
   MainController controller = (MainController) loader.getController();
```