# Setting the background of a GridPane (with or without JavaFx Scene Builder)

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I'm new to javafx and I am trying to set the background of a GridPane to an image(, or behind the GridPane). Setting the image in the fxml-file itself did not work. I tried to do this with the JavaFx Scene builder provided by oracle first and then later by manually adding this to the code with: `<GridPane style="-fx-background-image: url('board.jpg' ); ...`, but this resulted to nothing being changed when running the application.

I then resorted to setting the background image in the main-method and not the fxml-file. When I try to access the GridPane object (with getNamespace().get()) I get *null* back, so my problem here is that I can't seem to access the object to then set it's background to the image I want.

This what I tried most recently:

**sample.fxml**

```
<GridPane id="pain"...
```

**main.java**

```
FXMLLoader fxmlloader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
Parent root = fxmlloader.load();
GridPane pane = (GridPane)fxmlloader.getNamespace().get("pain");
pane.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('image.jpg');");
```

I already tried to find how to do this without success here:

[JavaFX 2.0 + FXML - strange lookup behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324799/javafx-2-0-fxml-strange-lookup-behaviour)

[JavaFX How to set scene background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738146/javafx-how-to-set-scene-background-image)

Comment: You need `fx:id`, not `id`. But the style option in FXML should work. Where is `image.jpg` located in relation to the FXML file? You may need to read the documentation on FXML [location resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution).

Comment: You sir, made my day! Thanks a lot. Such a small mistake, such a big difference. Thanks!